# actionbar style not override the style of action bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I use the code below to change the style of a tabbed activity in my application:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.



-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.



    -->

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- Action Bar them -->

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_appolo</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_appolo</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarText</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_action_launcher</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Appolo</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Appolo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

This is the `actionbar_tab_indicator` content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />
</selector>
```

I also use the code below for styles in style-v11 and style-v14:

```
...
      <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_appolo</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_appolo</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarText</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_action_launcher</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Appolo</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>

   <!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Appolo" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">


        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    </style>
...
```

But it is not changing the style of the tab bar.

I checked my code many times, I searched and reviewed all my notes but I can't find what the problem is. Does anyone have any answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in this part of code:

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_appolo</item>
<item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_appolo</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarText</item>
<item name="icon">@drawable/ic_action_launcher</item>
<item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Appolo</item>
```

and especially this line:

```
<item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Appolo</item>
```

this line should not be in the custom them that I want to use as my action bar theme. The right way is adding this under my custom app them so I remove this line from above part and add it under `AppBaseTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
     <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Appolo</item>
</style>
```

and now the code is working right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme.ActionBarStlye" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_appolo</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_appolo</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_action_launcher</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme.ActionBar.TabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs styles -->
<style name="ActionBarTheme.ActionBar.TabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

Also make sure you're using your theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme" >
```

I have noticed, with older versions of Android, the app crashes if the Theme is not a child of AppCompat. This should be a work around.

**EDIT:** you also forgot to put `android:` before `background`, `icon`, etc.

Comment: may you please describe what is the diffrence between you code and mine? you just changed the name of the last style?!

Comment: I changed it so that all of your styles are children of ActionBarTheme. I also changed the parent of your theme.

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad I updated my code, it should work now.

Comment: these are because of appCompact mode. you can see them in v11 and v14

Comment: I see. Have you tested my code yet to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, i tested it and it is not working.Please read the codes, all part is same and you just changed the name of the styles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62145/discussion-between-yaycoding-and-husein-behbudirad).

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your style xml file.

```
<item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs </item>

<style name="CustomActionBarTabs"parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_custom_actionbar_style</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that You have applied `app-theme` in

#### manifest file.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"  >
```

Comment: yes i have this line in my manifest:   "android:theme="@style/AppTheme". the colors of action bar is changing but the color of tabs is not changing

Comment: <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs</item>

Comment: as you can see in the code, I user this line too but it is not working